# I want to draw a bended / not-bended bi-metal that I can change with a parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf

In an attempt the working of a bi-metal, I want to make this drawing.

[image]

The code I made is this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,arrows.meta,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes,decorations.text,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.misc, positioning,shapes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\bimetal}[1]{
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 3/1/B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](#1:3){B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0,6pt){C};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](-4.8pt,4.3pt){D};
\draw[thick,double=black,double distance=5pt] (A) to[out=0,in=-130] (B);
\draw[thick,double=gray!50,double distance=5pt] (C) to[out=0,in=-130] (D);
\node[right] at (0,1.5) {verwarmen};
}

\bimetal{10}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think this code be done better, because now it is a lot of trial and error.

My question is: Can it be made with a parameter, so temperature could be positive (up), negatieve (down) or zero (horizontal)

Clarification of my question:

- the bi-metal is made by 4 points A-B the lower bar
- C-D the upper bar

although the drawing is ok for me in that way, but I want to make a macro like
\bimetal{}

With that angle I can control point B, but the in and out are not ok.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

with playing of some elementary geometry:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[below=1mm of a] (b);
\coordinate[above right=6mm and 24mm of a] (c);
\coordinate (d) at ($(c)+(320:1mm)$);   % 320 = 230+90
%
\draw[line width=1mm, gray] (a) to[out=0,in=230] (c);% 230 = 360-130
\draw[line width=1mm]       (b) to[out=0,in=230] (d);
\node[above right=11mm and 0mm of a] {verwarmen};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks but how can I make it bend to other way round, changing one parameter?

Comment: define this parameter and then use in given *mwe* :) seriously, clarify your question (by editing it). which parameter you like that will control your bi-metal? in my *mwe* is clear indicated relation between used parameters.

Comment: I hope my question is clear now?

Comment: you can use my *mwe* in your macro, but you need to define relationship between angles and length of geometry. already  for this you need two parameters :(.  all this mater of geometry, not latex. relations you can calculate with `pgfmath` engine, for example defining adequate `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro name>}{<expression>}`. see tikz & pgf manual, page 925